# Prove that a map is continuous and surjective, but is not a quotient map

Tags: general-topology

Could someone help me with the following problem?

Let $C_{n}$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by

\begin{equation}
C_{n}=\left\{x \times y: \left(x - \frac{1}{n}\right)^2 + y^2 = \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\right\}.
\end{equation}

Let $Y$ be the subspace

\begin{equation}
Y = \cup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}} C_n
\end{equation}
of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and let $X$ be the subspace $C_{1} \times \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{2} \times \mathbb{R}$. Define $g : X \to Y $ by the equation

\begin{equation}
g((x \times y) \times n) = \left( \frac{x}{n} , \frac{y}{n} \right).
\end{equation}

How could you prove that $g$ is continuous and surjective, but $g$ is not a quotient map?

Comment: The space $Y$ is known as the *Hawaiian earring*. By the way, you should write $(x,y)$ instead of $x \times y$.

Answer (score 3):

Continuity and surjectivity are relatively easy. The map is not a quotient map because an open arc of some $C_n$ containing the origin is not open in $Y$ (any neighbourhood of the origin intersects all circles $C_n$), but the pre-image of this arc under $g$ is open in $X$.

Answer (score 2):

Surjectivity: every point in $C_n$ has a preimage point in $(C_1,n)$.
Continuity: for every open set $U$ in $Y$ can be represented as an intersection of an open set $\bar U$ from $\mathbb R^2$, which means $U = \cup_k (\bar U \cap C_n)$. Preimage of this union is a union of preimages in the corresponding $(C_1, n)$, and thus itself an open set.

Why is it not a quotient map? Consider this set: $W = \{(x,y)\in Y: |y|>x\}$. The preimage of $W$ is open since it is a set of open arcs in the corresponding $(C_1, n)$ circles. But we can show that $W$ is not open because its complement in $Y$ is not closed. Indeed, all points in the sequence $(\frac{1}{n},0)$ are outside of $W$ but the sequence converges to $(0,0)$. But by the definition of the quotient space the set is open if and only if its preimage is open.

Comment: Thank you! but something is not clear to me. Why is the preimage of W an open set?

How can I prove that is a set of open arcs on the corresponding circles (C1,n)? I can't see this.

Comment: I've expanded my answer -- please let me know if it makes it clearer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Each $g_n :D_n = C_1 \times \{n\} \to Y, g_n(x,y,n) = (x/n,y/n)$, maps $D_n$ homeomorphically onto $C_n$. The $D_n$ are disjoint open subsets of $D = C_1 \times \mathbb Z_+$. Thus the map
$$g : D = \bigcup_n D_n \to Y = \bigcup_n C_n, g(\zeta) = g_n(\zeta) \text{ for } \zeta \in D_n$$
is a continuous surjection.

The set $X  = \{(2/n,0) \mid  n \in \mathbb Z_+\}$ is not closed in $Y$ because $\overline X \setminus X = \{(0,0)\}$. But $g^{-1}(X) = \{(2,0)\} \times \mathbb Z_+$ is closed in $D$, thus $g$ is no quotient map.

Comment: The point $(1,0) \notin C_{1}$, thus  $g^{-1}(X) = \varnothing$ ?

Comment: @Cal22 I made a correction. In fact, $(1/n,0) \notin C_n$.